# Link broken in SO blog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, blog

The [UserVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History) ticket link is broken in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/11/raising-a-red-flag/)

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090415094510/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/159703-allow-for-reporting-of-content-and-users-to-mods-and-or-team) is no more accessible. Should this be cleaned up?

[image]

Update:

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

Comment: It is not, Jeff left almost 6 years ago.  UserVoice was used before SO had a meta.  Expired.

Comment: cross site related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127898/158100

Comment: Also: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5605015#5605015  so don't expect this to be fixed or even fixable, not even in 6 to 8 weeks ....

Comment: I agree its challenging to fix this. But I navigated to this broken link in just 3 clicks from Review Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the post to remove the link to UserVoice (which we no longer use).

Thanks for reporting the issue.